# Run a script (or any command) as late as possible in the Android boot proccess

Tags: android-source, boot

I wish to run a script in the boot process, and I need it to run as late as possible, preferably after the actual Android GUI is available.

I tried placing it under 'on fs', in the init.rc, but it doesn't seem late enough, and I'm not sure the build I'm working with provides things like 'post-fs'.

So my question is actually split into two:

1. Where in the AOSP build folder can I start looking for the property list (Not very familiar with it, I'm a low-level guy) that can be used in init.rc (i.e. 'on property:name=value').
2. Is there a way to run the script only after the GUI is available?

Comment: You could consider triggering your script from application code utilizing a boot receiver...

Comment: Also keep in mind that it is possible for the Android layer to restart while the kernel stays up (typically looks like a reboot to the user even though it isn't), so decide if you want your "after the GUI is available" condition to be met only once per kernel boot, or for each GUI restart.